# JavaScript mousedown event reporting child node instead of expected node

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to add a simple `mousedown` eventlistener to a `DIV`.  The `DIV` has one child node, an `IMG`.  However, when the `mousedown` event fires, the `target` and `srcElement` properties of the event refer to the `IMG`, not the `DIV` node.  None of the event properties refer to the `DIV`. The handler is generic and expects the actual node somewhere in the event, and as a result is failing (it incorrectly is trying to operate on the `IMG` element).

I have tried both setting the `onmousedown` property of the element, as well as calling the element's `.addEventListener('mousedown', f, true)` which I expected from reading the documentation the `true` should dispatch the event directly to the `DIV` without first sending it to any child nodes.  Yet the child still is the only element that is reported as having received the event.  I also tried passing `false` instead of `true` with no change.

There is only one event handler added to the `DIV`, there are no other event handlers on the `IMG` or anywhere else.

In the past I haven't had code that is generic enough to require that it be able to know exactly which element has the event registered to it.  How do I get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget):

> Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses
>   the DOM. It always refers to the element the event handler has been
>   attached to as opposed to `event.target` which identifies the element on
>   which the event occurred.

Alternatively, on most browsers you can use `this`. However, I think this is a DOM0 behavior never standardized.

Comment: event.currentTarget is null

Comment: ah never mind... i was using console.log to log the object, and it's null there, but if I actually drop into the debugger during the event handler's scope it *is* the current target.

Comment: Getting used to `this` in handler can also create confusion when using event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your image to background of DIV node this problem solving easy.

Comment: But semantically, an image and a background image are different things.

Comment: Sure. If your object image is just for showing, you can set the image URL to DIV: **background-image: url();**